# sum of array based on key(Group by user)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum, array-sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkBSY.png)

This is my first array which i get from mysql

```
Array    
([0] => Array
    (
        [created_by] => 4
        [count] => 1
        [total] => 300
    )

[1] => Array 
    (
        [created_by] => 4
        [count] => 1
        [total] => 450
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [created_by] => 3
        [count] => 1
        [total] => 500
    )
```

)

I need a output as

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [created_by] => 4
        [count] => 2
        [total] => 750
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [created_by] => 3
        [count] => 1
        [total] => 500
    )
```

Sum of array total based on created_by
Need to group by created_by count.

Comment: Also show the PHP code where the source array is build if MySQL is involved also show the table structure with example data.. A MySQL query is much easier to get the array structure you need something like  `SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(total) AS total FROM table GROUP BY created_by`.. For now i vote close this question to be unclear read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask..

Comment: i have joined from two tables..not possible in mysql.any idea in php

Comment: "i have joined from two tables..not possible in mysql"  `COUNT(*)`, `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` also work on JOINED tables iám sure it's possible in pure MySQL only. So show the code and table structures with example data on sqlfiddle.com..